# Searchbar stops working when i type something

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, searchbar

SearchBar Automatically closes whenever i type something into it
Whenever i type a letter the searchbar closes and the value which i typed also disappears
. I used framer motion to make the slider and after typing a letter search results come but the styling of the slider component ruins.

```
import React from 'react'
import Header from './Header'
import LandingPage from './LandingPage'
import './style.css'


function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <LandingPage />
      
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Landing Page.js

```
import React, { useState , useEffect , useRef } from 'react'
import { motion } from 'framer-motion'
import songs from './Songs'
import './style.css'
export default function LandingPage() {
  const [panel , setPanel] = useState(false)
  const [filteredSongs , setFilteredSongs] = useState([...songs])
  const handleSearchBar = (e) => {
    const searchword = e.target.value;
    const filteredword = songs.filter(song => {
      return song.name.includes(searchword)
    })
    
      
    console.log(e.target.value)
    if(e.target.value.length === 0 ){
      setFilteredSongs([...songs])
      setPanel(false)
    }
    else{
      setPanel(true)
      setFilteredSongs([...filteredword])
    }
    console.log(e.target.value)
    console.log(e.target.value.length)

    
  }

  
  // Search Bar
  function SearchBar(props) {
    
    return (
  <div class="input-group input-group-lg" style={{
      width : '700px'
  }}>
    <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-lg" >Search Music </span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  onChange={props.manageSearch}/>
  </div>
    )
  }
  // Slider
  function Slider() {
    const carousel = useRef();

    const [width , setWidth] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
      
      setWidth(carousel.current.scrollWidth - carousel.current.offsetWidth)
    }, [])
  
  return (

    <div>
 


            {panel === false ? 
             <motion.div ref={carousel} className='carousel'>
            <motion.div className='inner-carousel' drag='x' dragConstraints={{
              right : 0 , left : -width,
            }}>
       
        { songs.map(song => {
          return (
        
            <motion.div className='item d-flex flex-column rounded-top mx-2' key={song.id}
            >
            <img src={song.image} alt=''/>
            <div>
              <h4 className='text-center'>{song.name}</h4>
              <p className='text-center'><a href='#' className='text-center'>{song.author}</a></p>
            </div>
            </motion.div>
          )
      
        })
        
        } 
        </motion.div>
        </motion.div> : 
         <motion.div ref={carousel} className='carousel'>
        <motion.div className='inner-carousel' drag='x' dragConstraints={{
          right : 0 , left : -width,
        }}>

        
       
        { filteredSongs.map(song => {
          return (
            <div className='item d-flex flex-column rounded-top mx-2' key={song.id}
            >
            <img src={song.image} alt=''/>
            <div>
              <h4 className='text-center'>{song.name}</h4>
              <p className='text-center'><a href='#' className='text-center'>{song.author}</a></p>
            </div>
            </div>
          )
      
        })
        
        } 
        </motion.div>
        </motion.div>
        }
      
    </div>
  ) 

}
//Main Return 
  return (
    <div className='bg-secondary landingpage d-flex align-items-center justify-content-sm-around flex-column' style={{
        width : '100vw',
        height : '100vh'
    }}>
      <SearchBar  manageSearch={handleSearchBar} />
      <Slider />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try  to the change like:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control"  onChange={handleSearchBar}/>
```

May this will help you.